# How to validate JSON against XSD schemas

Tags: json, xml, architecture, xsd

I know the title sounds impossible, give it a second. We have XSD schemas created by an open-standards industry group. In our service we'd like our customers to be able to use JSON or XML when supplying data. What's the best practice in a situation like this?

1. Convert JSON payloads to XML and validate against the XSD.
2. Convert the XSD to JSON Schema and validate each content-type against it's own schema
3. Convert the XSD to a class-based in language specification and do schema validation in code and then handle content negotiation in the api middleware
4. Secret super option

FWIW, these XSD schemas are not overly trivial: ~4000 lines long, multiple namespaces with a half-dozen common schemas shared between them. Changes are rare (one every 2 years) but new schemas are added much more frequently (10 per year)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about defining your application architecture rather than solving a coding problem. (Try the xml-dev mailing list, which relishes such problems).

Comment: I'm tempted to answer despite @MichaelKay's (correct) admonishment that this question is off-topic here.  If you state the industry standard, you *may* entice me.

Comment: @Micheal I checked it out before asking: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. I think it's just as valid to ask: what validation scheme should I use for this data as it is to ask what sort algorithm should I use for this set.

kjhughes - UBL (http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/UBL-2.1.html)

Answer (score 0):

> What's the best practice in a situation like this?

**Follow any existing industry standards for your interfaces.**  You've adopted [**UBL**](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/UBL-2.1.html) for XML.  Good.

Now, you want to add a [**JSON**](https://www.json.org/) interface too and are wondering whether to...

> 1. Convert JSON payloads to XML and validate against the XSD.
> 2. Convert the XSD to JSON Schema and validate each content-type against it's own schema
> 3. Convert the XSD to a class-based in language specification and do schema validation in code and then handle content negotiation in the api middleware

**None of the above.**  Implement OASIS's [**UBL 2.1 JSON Alternative Representation Version 1.0**](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/UBL-2.1-JSON/v1.0/UBL-2.1-JSON-v1.0.html) ***directly***.  For validation, use the [**JSON UBL schemas**](http://docs.oasis-open.org/ubl/UBL-2.1-JSON/v1.0/cnd02/json-schema/)  already developed.